# Error with selecting sysdate between time range

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to fetch the data for `sysdate-1` '00:00:00' between '23:59:59' time range. I have tried, but i am getting error.

This is my query..

```
select id_value, tn, LINE_TYPE_ID, ACCOUNT_TYPE_ID, PORT_ID, CURRENT_STATUS_ID, ERROR_CODE, ERROR_DESC, CRM_APP_CODE
from np_tn_dtls a
  join np_port_req_dtls b on A.NP_TXN_ID=B.NP_TXN_ID
  left join np_subscriber_dtls c on a.NP_TXN_ID=C.NP_TXN_ID
  left join np_subscriber_id_dtls d on D.SUBSCRIBER_ID=C.SUBSCRIBER_ID
where (b.REQUEST_START_TIME between sysdate-1 '00:00:00'
      AND sysdate '23:59:59') and (b.port_type_id != 2);
```

Please suggest me.

Comment: And the error you are getting is?

Comment: try `where b.REQUEST_START_TIME > sysdate - 1 and to_char(b.REQUEST_START_TIME, 'hh24:mi:ss') >= '00:00:00'  and to_char(b.REQUEST_START_TIME, 'hh24:mi:ss') <= '23:59:59'`

Comment: I am getting this error ORA-00905: missing keyword. The red mark marked at '00:00:00' time stamp.

Comment: Don't cast to char when you want to compare dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression is wrong:

```
between sysdate-1 '00:00:00'
  AND sysdate '23:59:59'
```

Use `trunc` to round the date, so you can write this:

```
between trunc(sysdate-1) AND trunc(sysdate)
```

However, `between` is [up to *and including*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions011.htm#SQLRF52147), so to prevent getting also request that happened exactly at midnight today, you can better write it like this:

```
b.REQUEST_START_TIME >= trunc(sysdate-1) AND 
b.REQUEST_START_TIME < trunc(sysdate)
```

Answer (score 1):

`sysdate '23:59:59'` is not a valid construction

use

```
    b.REQUEST_START_TIME >= trunc(sysdate-1)
AND b.REQUEST_START_TIME < trunc(sysdate)
```